# Make a drop down login form on the Zurb Foundation Framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Ok, well you see I have been able to successfully create a dropdown login form in Twitter Bootstrap. In Bootstrap it was much simpler, but this framework doesn't work that easily. This is what I am trying to achieve: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-A1GH5oiWNEI/UTg6JoR9kDI/AAAAAAAAAAM/g4BJNVkvLJ4/s1600/Drop-Down-Form-F3.png. Here is my current code: (I cut some parts out)

```
    <nav class="top-bar">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- Title Area -->
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">ChatAar</a></h1>
    </li>
    <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
    <a href="#" class="alert button" data-dropdown="hover1" data-options="is_hover:false">Login</a>
    <ul id="hover1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
    <!-- Login form here -->
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
            <div class="red"><?php echo $Login; ?></div>
                <p>Username:</p>
                <input name="user" type="text" class="field" id="user"/> 
                <p>Password:</p>
                <input name="pass" type="password" class="field" id="pass" value="" />
                    <br />
                <label style="text-color:white;">Remember Me For 30 Day's</lable>
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                <input name="page" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_GET['page']; ?>" />
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Log In" />
                    <br />
                <a href="forgotpassword.php">Password Recovery</a> | <a href="register.php">Sign Up</a>
             </div>
        </form>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

And this is what I get:
http://webymaster.hj.cx/public.php?service=files&t=cdf517da96a2ad178045198169958afb. I have tried normal drop downs but it doesn't work (sorry dont have a pic) then I came up with this but, its not the best. Please Help Thank You!

Comment: Is the question about Zurb Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap? They're different solutions for responsive design, and what works on one prbably won't work on the other.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Well about the Zurb Foundation Framework. How would I make it drop down and have a form inside? Thank you

Comment: Which Zurb Foundation version are you using?

Comment: @OmarQuazi You should take the time to vote, comment on and select an answer since people took the time to answer. Did either of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 9):

Using **Foundation 5**, this will get you close:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#" data-dropdown="signin">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
<div id="signin" class="f-dropdown small content" data-dropdown-content>
  <!-- signin form here -->
</div>
```

Note that the login form needs to be located *outside of* the `top-bar`, otherwise it will have badly mangled styles.

For a complete reference, examples, and ideas of how to customize it, check out Zurb's wonderful documentation on [dropdowns](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) and [forms](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on *chadoh*'s excellent answer, for anyone who's looking for something simple and ready to go:

```
<div id="login-dropdown" class="f-dropdown small content" data-dropdown-content="true">
    <h5>Log In:</h5>
    <form id="top-nav-login" action="login.xqy" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" tabindex="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="email" placeholder="********" tabindex="2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" class="button tiny success" value="Login" tabindex="3"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is just the dropdown part of the markup. You'll still need the top-bar and data-dropdown element from *chadoh*'s answer. Obviously add your own form elements as needed.